# Changing the foldername and file name under directory

Tags: python

I am trying to change the foldername, and the file names.  They all have a $, and I want a #.  Here is what I got

```
def cleanFiles(self):
    #directory = '/Users/eeamesX/work/data/Sept_1_upload/priority_2/transcriptsAudoSplits/09012015_331_male3_r1_seg1/IT_007/hell$o '
    directoryChosen = self.directoryChoice()
    print directoryChosen + "     you made it to files selected"
    self.listWidget.addItem(directoryChosen)
    #for file_names in os.listdir(directoryChosen):
        #self.listWidget.addItem(file_names)

    for n in os.listdir(directoryChosen):
        print n + "   made it here"
        if os.path.isfile(directoryChosen):
            print directoryChosen + "almost there"
            newname =  n.replace('$', '#')
            print newname + "    this is newname"
            if newname != n:
                os.rename(n,newname)
    print '\n--------------------------------\n'
    for n in os.listdir(directoryChosen):
        print n
        self.lblNamechange.show()
```

I have pinpointed my problem through the printing.  It is in the line

```
if os.path.isfile(directoryChosen):
```

It is not reading the files in the directory to change the filenames.  Any help?  Also, Will this change the foldername?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are passing is in fact a directory, then this:

`if os.path.isfile(directoryChosen):`

will never be True, because `isfile` checks whether what you are passing is in fact a file.

Running `help(os.path.isfile)` in your interpreter will show you:

```
isfile(path)
    Test whether a path is a regular file
```

What you want to use is actually `isdir`:

`if os.path.isdir(directoryChosen):`